# How to align images on the bottom of the website

Tags: html, alignment

I want to align images like shown in the Aligned Images link at the bottom of the website. I just mean that I want to place many movies dvd covers on the bottom of the page so it becomes easy to access any movies directly. So if someone hover the movie Blast than it will pop up. Can anyone help me out.

[image]

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you want. Do you want to see it fixed at all times at the bottom? Only when you get to the bottom? What?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
<img  src="http://i.imgur.com/KjuqA1l.png" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
```

Update:

```
<img  src="http://i.imgur.com/KjuqA1l.png" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;max-width:100%;">
```

Comment: I want to align as shown in the image. I don't want the image to be align at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwtp7pje/

Note that if you put the image inside of another div, you need to assign that div a `position: relative;` for it to work.

**Edit:** if you're looking to place several images at the bottom, place the images in a div like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://orig12.deviantart.net/2b79/f/2008/314/e/8/my___dark_knight___dvd_cover_by_esbe77.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://orig12.deviantart.net/2b79/f/2008/314/e/8/my___dark_knight___dvd_cover_by_esbe77.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://orig12.deviantart.net/2b79/f/2008/314/e/8/my___dark_knight___dvd_cover_by_esbe77.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

with css:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 33%;
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwtp7pje/1/

Comment: I want to align as shown in the image. I don't want the image to be align at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

this is in css

```
      .fix{
         position:fixed;
         bottom:0px;
           }
```

and your html

```
     <img src="yourimagepath" class="fix"/>
```

absolute: An absolutely  positioned based on its nearest relatively positioned parent element.

fixed: Fixed elements are completely independent on the web page. Regardless of any parents, a fixed position element will always be fixed at a point based on the window of browser